# Is there a speedy and memory efficient way to calculate the proportion of overlay between a polygon and high resolutiong raster in R?

Tags: r, overlay, polygon, raster, percentage

I need to calculate the proportion of each raster cell in a high resolution grid (raster stack with 8 layers) covered by a polygon using R.

My standard approach would be to use raster::rasterize(..., getCover = TRUE), however, this approach takes a very long time, particularly when the size of the polygon increases.

As an alternative, I tried cropping the raster stack to the extent of the polygon, transforming the raster stack to polygons and calculating the proportion from the intersection of the resulting shapes with the original polygon. This works well for small polygons but breaks down as the polygon increases, because R runs out of memory (I am limited to 16GB) or because the calculation of the intersection takes too long.

Here a reproducible example using my current solution with a very small shape file.

```
library(raster)
library(spex)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(data.table)

# setup a dummy example
r <- raster(nrow = 21600, ncol = 43200)
r[] <- 1:933120000
r_stack <- stack(r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r)

# get a small dummy shapefile
shp_small <- raster::getData(name = "GADM", country = "CHE", level = 2, download = TRUE)
shp_small <- st_as_sf(shp_small)[1, ]

# for comparison, use a big dummy shapefile
# shp_big <- raster::getData(name = "GADM", country = "BRA", level = 0, download = TRUE)

## Approach for a small shape file
stack_small <- raster::crop(r_stack, shp_small, snap = "out")

## transform to polygon
stack_small_poly <- spex::polygonize(stack_small)
stack_small_poly$ID <- 1:nrow(stack_small_poly)

## I can then perform the necessary calculations on the polygons to obtain 
## the proportional overlay

# transform to mollweide for area calculation
mollw <- "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
stack_small_crs <- st_crs(stack_small_poly)
stack_small <- st_transform(stack_small_poly, mollw)
stack_small_poly <- st_transform(stack_small_poly, mollw)

# calculate area for each cell
stack_small_poly$area_org <- st_area(stack_small_poly)

# transform to world equidistant cylindrical
stack_small_poly<- st_transform(stack_small_poly, 4087)
shp_small <- st_transform(shp_small, 4087)

# get call the cells that intersect with the shape (this might take a while)
i <- st_intersects(stack_small_poly, shp_small, sparse = FALSE)
stack_small_poly <- dplyr::filter(stack_small_poly, i)

# now calculate the extact intersection (this might take a while)
st_agr(stack_small_poly) <- "constant"
stack_small_poly <- st_intersection(stack_small_poly, st_geometry(shp_small))

# calculate the new areas and backtransform
stack_small_poly <- st_transform(stack_small_poly, mollw)
stack_small_poly$new_area <- st_area(stack_small_poly)
stack_small_poly <- st_transform(stack_small_poly, stack_small_crs)

# calculate proportion
stack_small_poly$proportion <- as.numeric(stack_small_poly$new_area/stack_small_poly$area_org)

# finally transform to data.table for subsequent analysis
st_geometry(stack_small_poly) <- NULL
setDT(stack_small_poly)
```

I am looking for a solution in R that is able to perform the task in 10-15 minutes (preferably faster) with a memory limit of 16 GB RAM for the shapefile representing Brazil (see shp_big in code above).

I am well aware that this optimum might not be achievable and every suggestion leading to a reduction in execution time and/or memory usage is more than wellcome.